# angular 2 ElementRef in es5

Tags: javascript, angular

My problem is that I'm trying to make an Attribute directive in angular 2 that allows me to define multiple default html attributes from one custom attribute. I'm trying to use it specifically on the input element. the problem arises in that i can't seem to get a reference to the element the attribute is attached to i know that using view query you can get references to child elements (elements that are part of the view) but because its an attribute directive it doesn't have a view and the element i am needing is the element within which the directive rests. here's the code i have so far. please note that it is all in es5 i am unable to use typescript or any other compiler.

parent component and bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.testing);
});
(function(app){
    app.testing=ng.core.Component({
        selector:"testing",
        //this is the element i need a reference to
        //i would like to assign the min max and step properties using one attribute 
        template:"<input type='range'  multiAttr='hello world' #input />",
        directives:[app.multiAttr],
    }).Class({
        constructor:[function(){}],
    });
})(window.app||(window.app={}));
```

multi attribute directive

```
(function(app){
    app.multiAttr=ng.core.Directive({
        selector:"[multiAttr]",
        inputs:["multiAttr"],
        queries:{"input":new ng.core.ElementRef()},
    }).Class({
        constructor:[function(){
        }],
        ngAfterViewInit:function(){
            //here is where i need my element reference 
            console.log(this.input);
            console.log(this.multiAttr);
        }
    });
})(window.app||(window.app={}));
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<testing></testing>
<script src='../jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../Rx.umd.min.js'></script>
<script src='../angular2-polyfills.min.js'></script>
<script src='../angular2-all.umd.js'></script>
<script src='multiAttr.js'></script>
<script src='testing.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the answer lies somewhere in ng.core.ElementRef but I can't figure out how to properly inject it into my script.

Comment: is `this.viewChild` anything of use?

Comment: if you're referring to ng.core.ViewChild that is used in a normal child query it doesnt help because its an attribute directive and thus doesn't have a view or children.

Comment: `"<input type='range'  [multiAttr]='input' #input />"`

Comment: @EricMartinez no that would give me a literal string "input"  and even if i made it evaluate all it would do is look for a variable named input on the testing component

Comment: No, that would not give you a literal "input" string. That would give you the element itself.

Comment: Is that because of the #input? And by the way you do need to evaluate it otherwise it just returns "input" because it doesn't evaluate the string as code without []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can inject the `ElementRef` in your directive:

```
var multiAttrDirective = ng.core.Directive({
  selector:"[multiAttr]",
  inputs:["multiAttr"]
}).Class({
  constructor:[ng.core.ElementRef, function(eltRef){
    console.log(eltRef);
    console.log(eltRef.nativeElement);
  }],
  ngAfterViewInit:function(){
    (...)
  }
});
```

The `eltRef.nativeElement` returns the DOM element corresponding to your input.

Comment: How to import `ElementRef` into your module? Via `imports`?